# Datatables can showing data/result but sometimes(often) get error 404 if load or search data

Tags: laravel, yajra-datatable

I have a table and showing data and using Datatables Yajra to get search and pagination . This datatables is work ,showing data , all function is OK .

But if i reload this page,search some words , is often to showing error :

> DataTables warning: table id=table1 - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

But , if i load again its normal . i dont know what happen , my script is not fault because this data is showing .

I am using laravel and still using **Php Artisan Serve** to start project. some poeple give me solution to using Xampp or Wampp , but i cant use it because its make me changed so many script.

how i can solved this ? if you using this datatbles , is you have same problem like i am ?

Comment: Hi, those people are right ;) it's a well known bug. It's even mentioned on official github page: https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables#user-content-php-artisan-serve-bug

Comment: Hmm oke sir , i need to think again about this , thanks you verymuch

Comment: I got the same problem, before I also faced the same problem on local machine, but on live server there are no any issue